# BIRT parameter dataSet

Tags: birt

I've into BIRT a query like this

```
SELECT a.1, a.2, a.3 FROM a WHERE a.4 = 1
```

then I write another query as

```
SELECT b.1, c.2, c.3 FROM b join C on b.1=c.1 WHERE b.2=?
```

I would use to parameter, instead of '?', all values of column a.1 from first query. It's possible in BIRT?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using [joint datasets](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/eclipse_birt_report_retrieving-data.3.7.html), as discussed in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets), but if both queries are on the same database then it would be easier to combine the two queries, like so:

```
SELECT b.1, c.2, c.3 
FROM a
join b on a.1 = b.2
join C on b.1 = c.1 
where a.4 = 1
```

Or if you only want distinct values of a.1, like this:

```
SELECT b.1, c.2, c.3 
FROM b 
join C on b.1 = c.1 
where exists (select null from a where a.4 = 1 and a.1 = b.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood what you want to do, you can use one dataset as a parameter for another dataset.

So in your case, you make a dataset of your first sql. Then you go to your parameters and make a new parameter that is linked to your first dataset.
then you go to your second sql and you link your "?" to that new parameter (with the first dataset)
[image]

you save your parameter

Your second dataset parameter should look like this:
[image]