# Chart from 4 different data sets in BIRT

Tags: charts, dataset, birt

I am generating a report in BIRT and need to include a chart in it.
My report has four data sets. I need the chart to use four different columns from these charts and the X-axis to have the date range.
Is there a way to use four different data sets in the same chart?

If not can I bind a single table to four different data sets.

Any kind of help will be very helpful.

Thank you for all you time.

Regards

---

Thank you Mark and Tom!!

Even I was thinking combining the queries and then filtering it using expressions in BIRT would be good idea.

The issue I have is I am using 4 different queries, all come from the same data source. They use different conditions. I am not able to undersatnd how to combine them.

The data range and a condition seperates the queries, does anyone have a idea how would I be able to combine them?

Comment: UNIONing the results would be the obvious way - if you add your queries (or simplified versions of them, for ease of comprehension) to the question, we may be able to offer further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your datasets first before you can use them in a chart.

Answer (score 0):

A chart can only take data from a single dataset, but as noted in Tom's answer, you can join datasets together.

There are details of how to join separate datasets together to create joint datasets in BIRT in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets).

However (as noted in the linked answer), if your multiple datasets are from the same (SQL) datasource, I recommend combining the queries - this is because joint datasets tend to have relatively poor performance.