# BIRT: Using information from one Dataset as parameter of an other

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

i'm creating some BIRT-Reports with Eclipse. Now i got the following problem.
I've got two datasets (Set one named diag, set two named risk). In my report i produce fpr every data in diag a region with an diag_id. Now i tried to use this diag_id as input parameter for the second dataset (risk). Is this possible, and how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link one dataset to another in BIRT, you can either:

- Create a subreport within your report that links one dataset to another via an input parameter - see [this Eclipse tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/subreport.13.2.html).

or:

- Create a joint dataset that explicitly links the two datasets together - see the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets/3650884#answers).

Alternatively, if both datasets come from the same relational database, you could simply combine the two queries into a single query.

Comment: The first link is broken (strange how page works).  I think [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/sub-TutT8LinkOrdersSubrpttoMasterRpt.html?resultof=%22%6c%69%6e%6b%65%64%22%20%22%6c%69%6e%6b%22%20%22%64%61%74%61%73%65%74%73%22%20%22%64%61%74%61%73%65%74%22%20) should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scripted data sources, you could use variables.

Add a variable through the Eclipse UI called "diag_id".

In the **fetch** script of **diag**, set diag_id:

```
vars["diag_id"] = ...;         // store value in Variable.
```

Then, in the **open** script of **risk**, use the diag_id however you need to.

```
diag_id = vars["diag_id"];
```

This implies that placement of **risk** report elements are nested inside the **diag** repeating element so that diag.fetch will happen before each risk.open.