# Is it possible to setup BIRT to use multiple datasources within single dataset

Tags: sql, dataset, report, datasource, birt

Is it possible to create birt report in which I will have two data sources and one dataset that uses data from both datasources?

Comment: have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets

Comment: Yes I have seen it and tried this solution, however I got exception when joining two datasets, becouse whan of the datasets contains parameter (?) which is linked to report parameters. The exception message is "cannot link to parameter that is null".

Comment: did you try setting a default value for the parameter?  What version of BIRT are you using?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try to set the default value of the parameter. Now it works :) I'm using Birt 4.2.1 (Eclipse Juno).