# BIRT report table data from multiple datasources

Tags: birt

We have multiple datasources (with same structure) located at various locations, I want to fetch data from multiple datasources and display it one table. For e.g. We have a tabled called Employee with three columns. We have to retrieve this employee table data from all datasources and need to display it in one table. Can anybody help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many is multilple? The answer for 2 or 3 is going to be much differnt than the answer for 200 - 300.

Comment: Are you using the opensource or commercial version of BIRT?

Comment: We beed to collect data from two instances and merge them (UNION) and need to generate report or sometimes need perform aggregations on the resulted data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create BIRT report based on multiple data sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets)

Comment: You answer is in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets I flagged this question as a duplicate.

Comment: This question is posted with more accurate wording [here](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34163-union-of-datasets-and-data-from-multiple-datasources/) there is a link only answer to a [Dev share](http://developer.actuate.com/community/devshare/_/designing-birt-reports/simple-union-dataset-r1557)

Comment: @JamesJenkins Thank you for your help. And the Question in the link you have suggested above was asked by me only in Dev share. Got a perfect answer by Mica. Thanks Mica.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new join datasource. You will find more information here: [How to create BIRT report based on multiple data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643030/how-to-create-birt-report-based-on-multiple-data-sets)

Comment: This is probably better as a comment as it simply links to an existing answer on SO.  Also if the user has 200 data sources, then join data sets would be an extremly painfull solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the above said link will guide us for joinings. But I want to achieve UNION of datasets from two instances. Both data sets will have similar columns. Need perform UNION of those two datasets and sometimes able to perform aggregations on that resulted dataset.

Comment: @GSateesh you might want to read [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then try and write a new question that better asks what you want to know, and what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: @James Jenkins , I agree that the question doesn't include the term UNION of datasets. I have searched a lot but found results for joinings of datasets from multiple instances only. I have two database instances and need to collect data from both instances and display it in a single table. For. e.g I have an Employee table in both instances and one have 50 records and other have 100 records. Now I need to generate report with table having these 150 records. And also sometimes can be able to perform aggregations on this combined data.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround for Excel reports generated using union of multiple datasets :**

We can create different datasets from the available different datasources. Then, we can create a table with one dataset. And delete the footer for this table.

Then we can create one more table. This time deleting the header, footer for this second table, keeping only detail row. Now we can map the another dataset from another datasource to this table.

This has given the desired result when I generate report using excel.

Hope this answer helps !!